# How to trigger or send intent continously (without on button click)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am tryiny to update my edittext in UI. I have a service from where I send a intent by clicking a button and update in the UI. Everything works fine. But I would like to send intent without button click.

What I tried was to put my Intent in a method and call it `oncreate` in service but even then it been just called once.

```
public class myService extends service {
 onCreate{
     sendMessage();
}

 private void sendMessage(){
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.app.SEND");
    intent.putExtra("KEY", (String) Number);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

When I do like this, I just send empty string which is not useful. And even then just once.

Can I send intent continously ? So that It updates my UI once it receives input ? Any possible way to do it ?

I would like to send intent every 5 seconds.

Comment: From where you sending _Number_ in intent?

Comment: from `service` (not IntentService)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TimerTask with IntentService for scheduled jobs.
ex:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //some execution
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, 5000);
```

Comment: Can I use TimerTask in normal service too ? I would like to send intent every `5 seconds` on repeat mode

Comment: Yes, you can use with Service.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it !

Comment: ex: Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                |//some execution
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, 5000);

Comment: Can you add this to your answer. It will helpful for others too. Thanks man :)

Comment: Do I need kill it onDestroy ? or something like that ?

Comment: I you use Service, tie it to the life cycle of service